# Stop windows service before perform the uninstallation

Tags: windows-installer, custom-action, orca

I have an installer that installs few components including windows service, after it installed it'll start the service that installed onto the system using CustomAction.

The problem when I uninstall the application, the installer asks to close the application before continue.

[image: Error Dialog]

I created a custom action that will stop the service, and I scheduled it with Uninstall actions.

But its not executed until I press OK for the error dialog after manually stop the service.

It failed on Win7, but I tested the same MSI on WinXP and worked fine (The custom action executed before checking the file In-use)!!!

I'm using VS2010 setup project to create the installer, but I don't have problem to modify it (using Orca for example) after build.

Here is the content of the InstallExecuteSequence Table :

[image]

I found that the [InstallValidate](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa369546%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) action that check for In-Use files, but I can't sequence my custom action that stop the service before it because its before [InstallInitialize](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa369535%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) action that require all custom actions to be after it ([ICE77 Evaluator](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa369030%28v=vs.85%29.aspx))

> ICE77 posts an error if an in-script custom action is sequenced before
>   the InstallInitialize action or after the InstallFinalize action.

What should I do, shall I use the [MSIRESTARTMANAGERCONTROL](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa370377%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) property that specifies whether the Windows Installer package uses the FilesInUse Dialog functionality, but I need to notify the user about the other in-use  files.

Comment: I face the same issue with windows installer in VS2015. How did you get rid off this?

Comment: You need to apply the answer below, but because you're using VS installer project, you won't be able to automatically add that row to that table. I'd suggest to create a post-build action to execute -for example- a JScript file that insert that row manually (check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8318920/insert-into-removefile-table-in-msi) for a sample row insertion

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**There are built-in features for this in Windows Installer - no custom action necessary**. In fact I would strongly advice against using a custom action for this unless your service is very special (for example, slow to stop, or in need of shutting down a lot of resources and you need to verify that it does so). Most normal services stop within half a minute or so. I am not sure how long the Windows Installer Engine is configured to wait for the service to stop.

The **[ServiceControl table](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa371634%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)** of MSI is the "under the hood" feature for this. Most installation tools provide wizard like or GUI elements to control this in a simpler fashion though.

Here is the service control view in one Installshield version:

[image]

Comment: This ALMOST worked for me, but there seems to be something missing.  IS would install/remove the service, but it couldn't run after being installed like this! When I use my custom install, part of that is providing a class name for the service found inside the exe. There is no argument here for that. (This service is written in Python btw, but converted to an exe with pyInstaller).  I could install/uninstall via a CA, but I'm then stuck on the original question posted here!